# How to open next drawer on click of a specific fragment of previous drawer item

Tags: java, android, xml, navigation, drawer

In my app i want to open new drawer on click of an item of navigation bar in previous drawer of navigation drawer in android . like now i had mainactivity.java and fragments are involved on that activity . Now what i want that when i click on any item of mainactivity.java drawer item then it must open another drawer with different values in item i am attaching my code of mainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    NavigationView mNavigationView;
    FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
    FragmentTransaction mFragmentTransaction;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_coordinator);

        /**
         *Setup the DrawerLayout and NavigationView
         */

             mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
             mNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.shitstuff) ;

        /**
         * Lets inflate the very first fragment
         * Here , we are inflating the TabFragment as the first Fragment
         */

             mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
             mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
             mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView,new TabFragment()).commit();
        /**
         * Setup click events on the Navigation View Items.
         */

             mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
             @Override
             public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();



                 if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.nav_item_home) {
                     FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                     fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView,new coordinatorPanelFragment()).commit();

                 }


                 if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.nav_item_fllclass) {
                    FragmentTransaction xfragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    xfragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView,new fillClassFragment()).commit();
                }
///

                 if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.nav_item_fillstudent) {
                     FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                     fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView,new fillStudentFragment()).commit();

                 }


                 if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.nav_item_fillschedule) {
                    FragmentTransaction xfragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    xfragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView,new fillscheduleFragment()).commit();
                }


                 if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.nav_item_seebunk) {
                    FragmentTransaction xfragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    xfragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView,new seeBunkedStudentFragment()).commit();
                }

                 if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.nav_item_cus) {
                     FragmentTransaction xfragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                     xfragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView,new ContactusFragment()).commit();
                 }

                 if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.nav_item_help) {
                     FragmentTransaction xfragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                     xfragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView,new helpCoorFragment()).commit();
                 }





                 return false;
            }

        });

        /**
         * Setup Drawer Toggle of the Toolbar
         */

                android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar toolbar = (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
                ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,mDrawerLayout, toolbar,R.string.app_name,
                R.string.app_name);

                mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

                mDrawerToggle.syncState();

    }
```

These was my code for making one drawer with 6 items now i want that when i click on any item then it must open an specific drawer of that perticular fragment , i had searched but not found answer on google .It is same as app of google drive .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just see these example i hope they will help for your problem .
http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

It is tutorial of Android Sliding Menu using Navigation Drawer . The required code is i am pasting here :-

```
private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // display view for selected nav drawer item
            displayView(position);
        }
    }

     /**
     * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
     * */
    private void displayView(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new HomeFragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new FindPeopleFragment();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new PhotosFragment();
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new CommunityFragment();
            break;
        case 4:
            fragment = new PagesFragment();
            break;
        case 5:
            fragment = new WhatsHotFragment();
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }
```